# static block vs initializer block vs constructor in inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism, static-block

i find this example and i want to understand the logic behind it ? how constructors and static blocks and initializer blocks works in inheritance ? in which stage each one is called ?

```
public class Parent {

    static {
        System.out.println("i am Parent 3");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("i am parent 2");
    }

    public Parent() {
        System.out.println("i am parent 1");
    }

}

public class Son extends Parent {

    static {System.out.println("i am son 3");}
    {System.out.println("i am son 2");}

    public Son() {
        System.out.println("i am son 1");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Son();
    }
}
```

the output is :

```
i am Parent 3
i am son 3
i am parent 2
i am parent 1
i am son 2
i am son 1
```

Comment: You have already submitted the answer to your own question.

Comment: Instead of using numbers use proper names like static block, initializer block, constructor to make output clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A static block is called once, when the class is loaded and initialized by the JVM. An instance initializer is executed when an instance of the class is constructed, just like a constructor.

Static and Instance initializers are described in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6)

Comment: And, evidently, it is called before the constructor.

Comment: @anorton A class has to be initialized before it can be instantiated.

Answer (score 13):

You need to know that

1. first instruction in constructor is invoking constructor of its parent class `super(params)` or if you want to use default constructor `super()`. In case of default constructor you don't have to write it explicitly.
2. code in initializer block is moved to every constructor right after `super(...)` call
3. static block is executed when class is initialized which is done after it is fully loaded (with its parent classes) by JVM.

So classes are compiled into classes similar to this.

```
public class Parent {
    static {
        System.out.println("Parent static block");
    }

    public Parent() {
        super();
        {
            System.out.println("Parent initializer block");
        }
        System.out.println("Parent constructor");
    }

}

public class Son extends Parent {

    static {
        System.out.println("Son static block");
    }

    public Son() {
        super();
        {
            System.out.println("Son initializer block");
        }
        System.out.println("Son constructor");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Son();
    }
}
```

To be able to execute `main` method from `Son` class JVM needs to *load* code of this class (and classes it extends). After class is fully loaded JVM *initialize* its static content which involves executing static blocks (yes, there can be more then one static blocks in one class). To fully load `Son` class JVM needs to know details about its parent class so it will fully load `Parent` class before `Son` which means it will also execute its static blocks before static blocks in `Son` class.

So output will look like:

- `Parent static block`
- `Son static block`

Now in `main` method you are invoking `Son` class constructor via `new Son()` which code looks like

```
super();
{
    System.out.println("Son initializer block");
}
System.out.println("Son constructor");
```

Since its `super()` refer to `Parent` class constructor, which is

```
super();// this will invoke Object constructor since Parent 
        // doesn't extend anything (which means it extends Object class)
{
    System.out.println("Parent initializer block");
}
System.out.println("Parent constructor");
```

as result you will see

- `Parent initializer block`
- `Parent constructor`

This handles `Parent#constructor()` executed with `super()` so next you will see code from Son constructor after `super()` which will generate

- `Son initializer block`
- `Son constructor`

---

To see that classes will be loaded even before you use `Son` constructor or even `main` method you can just print something before using `Son` constructor like

```
System.out.println("ABC                      // before new Son()");
new Son();
```

which will result in

```
Parent static block
Son static block
ABC                      // before new Son()
Parent initializer block
Parent constructor
Son initializer block
Son constructor
```

Comment: There is no 'in the meantime' about it. The static initializer is  invoked first, and once, when the class is first loaded and initialized, which may be hours or weeks before any constructor is called. You haven't made that clear.

Comment: @EJP You are right, removed it.

Comment: I'm not just commenting on those three words. You haven't separated class loading and initialization from construction at all.

Comment: Note that `Son` should be loaded by the JVM to invoke `main`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Exactly. Nothing to do with construction.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis EJP you are right, working on it.

Answer (score 2):

Static block called  when your  class is loaded and your class is first loaded by classloader in jvm so first they get executed

then you create object so your parent init block is called then your parent constructor due to constructor chaining in java then derived class init block then derived class constructor

Answer (score 1):

Static block gets executed when the class is loaded into JVM whereas constructor block gets executed when an instance is created.

A static initializer is the equivalent of a constructor in the static context. You will certainly see that more often than an instance initializer.