# Java - Why the instance block is called after the constructor or order wise in the constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, static-block

As we know that the `instance block` is called before the `constructor`. [Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6), [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504726/static-block-vs-initializer-block-vs-constructor-in-inheritance) etc.

So, the output that we expect from the code below:

```
class Test{
    static { System.out.println("Static Block"); }
    { System.out.println("Instance Block"); }
    Test(){
        System.out.println("Constructor Body");
        { System.out.println("Constructor Instance Block"); }
    }
}
class TestApp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Should Be:

```
Static Block
Instance Block

Constructor Instance Block
Constructor Body
```

Then why i am getting the following output:

```
Static Block
Instance Block

Constructor Body
Constructor Instance Block
```

But if i change the order of the statements in `constructor` like:

```
class Test{
    static { System.out.println("Static Block"); }
    { System.out.println("Instance Block"); }
    Test(){
        { System.out.println("Constructor Instance Block"); }
        System.out.println("Constructor Body");
    }
}
```

Then it outputs the expected result but this should not be the way because the docs says that `instance block` is called before the `constructor`.

Why the `instance block` is called after the `constructor` body or we can say why it is called in order wise ?

Comment: `{ System.out.println("Constructor Instance Block"); }` is not an initialization block. It's just a random code block in the constructor.

Comment: There is no such concept as a constructor instance block. All code within any method or constructor is executed in order. *(Well, except for some compiler optimizations, but that's another story.)*

Comment: Instance initializers are not called *before* the constructor. They are inlined into all constructors which invoke `super`, in between the call to `super` and the rest of that constructor's body.

Comment: Where the `instance blocks` and `static blocks` are applicable and allowed to be used for their real meaning, one place that i know is `class`, are there any other places as well where these are also applicable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{ System.out.println("Constructor Instance Block"); }` is not an `instance block`, but yet another common line of code in a method(in your case, the constructor). So it excute AFTER the `System.out.println("Constructor Body");` , which is natural.

Comment: So, you mean there is not concept of `instance block` and `static block` within the `constructor`?

Comment: Exactly. They are used within a class, not a method(a constructor is also a method.)

Comment: Please can you tell where the `instance blocks` and `static blocks` are applicable and allowed to be used for their real meaning, one place that i know is in the `class`, are there any other places as well where these are also applicable?

Comment: As far as I know, they can only be used within a class.

Comment: @SunnyKhan Also note that they cannot be placed in an inner class, but can be placed in a static nested class(which has a `static` keyword).

Comment: @ZhaoGang correct. They can only appear in a [`ClassBodyDeclaration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-19.html).

Comment: @ZhaoGang - You mean `class{ class{ ... } }` and `static class{ class{ ... } }`?

Comment: @Sunny Khan You can read further here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Answer (score 1):

`static initializers` and `instance initializers` are corresponding to class and its creation (see: [Static block vs. initializer block in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12550146/7841643)).

That's why it must be placed in the **body** of the class.

Otherwise (for example, in method body), your `{...}` will be considered as *a block of instructions* (as in `C` language). If you try to put the construction `static {...}` elsewhere (not in class body) you will get a compilation error.